# How do I add design-time properties to this XBL control?

Tags: orbeon

Using Orbeon, I have the following XBL for a simple control:

```
<xbl:xbl xmlns:xh="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
     xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
     xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
     xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
     xmlns:xxi="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xinclude"
     xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
     xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
     xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
     xmlns:xbl="http://www.w3.org/ns/xbl"
     xmlns:xxbl="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xbl"
     xmlns:nrs="http://nrs.foo/2014/xml/xbl">

<xbl:script src="/xbl/nrs/foo/foo.js"/>

<xbl:binding id="nrs-foo" element="nrs|foo" xxbl:mode="lhha binding value">

     <metadata xmlns="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-builder">
        <display-name lang="en">Foo</display-name>
        <templates>
            <view>
                <nrs:foo>
                    <xf:label ref=""/>
                    <xf:hint ref=""/>
                    <xf:help ref=""/>
                    <xf:alert ref=""/>
                </nrs:foo>
            </view>
        </templates>
    </metadata>

    <xbl:template>
        <xf:group xxbl:scope="outer">

            <xf:group xbl:attr="model context ref bind">

                <!-- Constructor -->
                <xf:group xxbl:scope="inner">
                    <xxf:script id="xf-en" ev:event="xforms-enabled">YAHOO.xbl.nrs.foo.instance(this).init();</xxf:script>
                </xf:group>

            </xf:group>

            <xf:input class="nrs-foo-json" ref="xxf:binding('nrs-foo')" xxbl:scope="inner" />

        </xf:group>
    </xbl:template>
</xbl:binding>
```

.. and accompanying JS module:

```
(function() {
var $ = ORBEON.jQuery;
var Document = ORBEON.xforms.Document;

YAHOO.namespace("xbl.nrs");
YAHOO.xbl.nrs.Foo= function() {};
ORBEON.xforms.XBL.declareClass(YAHOO.xbl.nrs.Foo, "xbl-nrs-foo");
YAHOO.xbl.nrs.Foo.prototype = {

    fooInput       : null,

    init: function() {
        var self = this;

        self.fooInput = $(this.container).find( '.nrs-foo-json' );

        // get design time property
    },

};
})();
```

How would I modify the XBL to get a design-time property (say a string called 'URL', that I can configure on the properties panel in the form designer), that is stored in the form definition and I can access in the JS code (at place marked by comment)?

Answer (score 0):

Check how it is done in [`autocomplete.xbl`](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources-packaged/xbl/orbeon/autocomplete/autocomplete.xbl), and more specifically at the the content of `<control-details>` inside `<metadata>`. In that case the value set in Form Builder through the *Control Settings* dialog ends up in the `resource="..."` attribute on the control, and accessed in the XBL through the `resource-avt` variable.

(Note that there are some complications there as we want the value to be interpreted as an AVT, and the variable to be accessible both in the inner and outer scope, but hopefully this example helps you get the idea.)

Comment: I had already looked at `autocomplete.xbl`, and it was not particularly enlightening. Without a clear idea of all the layers of objects, and their interrelationships, it is near impossible to work out what is going on, without **lots** of trial-and-error. And the documentation is only minimally useful. I had hoped for a more constructive and to-the-point answer.

Comment: I agree, this is complicated and not particularly well documentated. Writing full documentation is beyond the scope of what I can do answering here on Stack Overflow, but if there is anything in particular in `autocomplete.xbl` that isn't clear, just let me know, and I'll do my best to explain it.